# self sizing cells custom sub view and how resize the sub view for contentview

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

1. add sub view for uitableviewcell contentview
2. i need resize the sub view
3. Used self-sizing-cells

now error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHWMu.png)

Comment: the issue with you given constraint is not proper.

Comment:  I am poor english ,like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603401/how-to-update-nslayoutconstraint-in-a-uitableviewcell-of-dynamic-height